# Display formatted price and currency symbol issue in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, currency, price

I added a PHP code snippet to my store, but I have the following problem:
The code show the currency symbol and the amount like this “You save: $20”, but in my country the currency symbol is over the number like this “You save: 20 PLN”.

Just need to replace the value of this code, but I don’t know how. I tried everything without success.

```
<p class="you_save_price">You save: <?php echo $currency_symbol .''. number_format($saved_amount, 2, '.', ''); ?></p>               
        <?php       
    }
```

I try to change the position, but it doesn't work… It throws a syntax error.

How to replace the price amount position and the currency symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use WooCommerce dedicated `wc_price()` function instead, like:

```
    <p class="you_save_price">You save: <?php echo wc_price($saved_amount); ?></p>  
    <?php       
}
```

or even better:

```
    <p class="you_save_price"><?php printf( __('You save: %s'), wc_price($saved_amount) ); ?></p>   
    <?php       
}
```

Both should work as expected.

**Note:** The WooCommerce price formatting function *wc_price()* uses your shop formatting price and currency settings and handle multicurrency when enabled by an additional plugin.